# Animate certain letters disappearing from a word, and then the rest of the letters moving together to fill the empty spaces

Tags: javascript, css

If the word were CANDY, the letters A and D would fade out, and then the remaining letters C, N, Y would move together and fill the spaces to read CNY instead of C N Y.

I'm not sure if you can do this with just CSS3 or if you have to use JavaScript, but either is fine. I also want the animation to loop infinitely, with CNY turning back into CANDY.

Comment: Voting to close this as "too broad" seems frankly ridiculous.

Comment: Unless, of course, close voters are using "too broad" as a proxy for "no effort". Although "no effort" is a valid reason for **down** voting, it's not the same as "too broad" and does not merit close voting in and of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class with an animation to apply to the characters to be faded in and out. The animation simultaneously changes to width to 0, and the opacity to 0.

> I also want the animation to loop infinitely, with CNY turning back into CANDY.

That's what `animation-iteration-count: infinite` and `animation-direction: alternate` do.

```css
.fade { 
  animation-name: fade; 
  animation-duration: 3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 @keyframes fade {
  from { width: 1em; opacity: 1; }
  to   { width: 0px; opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
C<span class="fade">A</span>N<span class="fade">D</span>Y
```

Comment: Thank you!I admit, I was only expecting to receive feedback on whether you can do this with just CSS or if it would require JavaScript. I was having a ton of trouble with wording my google searches to try to find a way to do it with only CSS.After looking at your code, I was surprised how easy it is to do with CSS. I've used basic CSS animations before but didn't realize the gaps would close by themselves by changing the display to 'inline-block'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good CSS candidate. I'd make a series of `<span>` or a `<div>` display-block float:left, each containing one letter, and stack each of those divs or spans in a javascript array. Then probably use jQuery to run an alpha tween on the letters you want to remove -- you can't use fadeOut because once they become invisible, the float probably won't work anymore. Use a callback to a second tween that moves the letters one character left whenever one to the left of it in the array is finished fading out, then remove that character from the array.

Comment: *I don't think this is a good CSS candidate.* But isn't this exactly what CSS animation was designed to do?

Comment: For preset animations like a fade-out, yes. Or for sliding something, yes. For combining those effects in a timed way on a bunch of dynamically generated DOM elements, you'd need to use listeners on the first animation to trigger the second one, so you'd be using javascript anyway, and it'd probably be less work to use jquery .animate than write the animations in pure CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are saying. Is it, "if the OP had asked a different question, he might have needed to use JS"? That's surely possible, but he asked the question he did, which can easily be handled with CSS transitions/animations, as can the great majority of animations that used to be done "by hand" in the bad old days.

Comment: I just assumed he wanted something where you could take an arbitrary string and do this to an arbitrary set of characters, causing some to fade and the rest to move smoothly together. I mean, in most cases I can think of where I'd need to do this, I'd want it to be reused, not as a one-off static HTML/CSS page.